# Generic action result with Bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics

Is it possible to have a ActionResult with a signature of:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction<T>([Bind(Prefix = typeof(T).Name)] T data)
{
  MapAndUpdateModel<T>(data);
  return Content(Boolean.TrueString);
}
```

I can't seem to use `typeof(T).Name` ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute arguments must be types or compile-time constants.  You can't call a method (the Name property getter) to supply a value to an attribute.

Unfortunately, BindAttribute is consumed by the MVC innards in long-ish hard-coded call chain without a trivial extension hook.  If you want to add a similar attribute that would allow inference of the prefix, this is possible, but you would pretty much need to replace the ControllerActionInvoker merely in order to change the parameter binding behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i already know this. I was asking if there is a way to implement this in some other way?

Comment: There is, but it's non-trivial.  See the addition to my answer.